# Button inside UpdatePanel doesn't fire method

Tags: html, asp.net

I have this code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelRegDDL" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>                                      
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="Crear Coordinador" OnClick="verificarCorreoServer" class="btn btn-success"  UseSubmitBehavior="False" aria-hidden="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've done this because I didn't want the button to refresh page, but now the button doesn't fire the method verificarCorreoServer. I don't know what else to do. I've seen a lot of question related to this but nothing work for me, the method never fires inside the UpdatePanel. If I put the button outside the UpdatePanel, the button fires the method but refreshes the page. Need your help please !

Edit: this is the method code

```
public void verificarCorreoServer(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ControladorUsuario cu = new ControladorUsuario();            
        Usuario user = cu.ObtenerUsuario(correo.Value);
        if (user != null)
        {
            //something
        else
        {                
            Usuario nuevoUsuario = new Usuario();
            nuevoUsuario.nombres = nombre.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.apellidos = apellido.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.correo = correo.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.password = contraseña.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.rut = rut.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.carrera = "";
            nuevoUsuario.fono = telefono.Value;
            nuevoUsuario.codigoRol = 1;
            nuevoUsuario.codigoSede = ddlSede.SelectedIndex+1;
            nuevoUsuario.estado = "Activo";
            cu.InsertarUsuario(nuevoUsuario);


        }
    }
```

As I said, the method works if Button is outside the UpdatePanel, inside it doesn't work.

Edit 2: I have an interruption point on the first line of the method. Never reaches if Button is inside the Update Panel. I don't know why the method is being ignored.

Comment: Include the method code. Being that the button is the only thing inside your update panel, if your method is modifying anything other than the button, it's not going to work as you expect.

Comment: I don't think the method code affects something. I posted it anyways.

Comment: Do me a favor and try removing the entire `<Triggers>` section, and remove `childrenAsTriggers` and `UpdateMode` attributes from the update panel. If the *only* thing in your update panel is this button, it isn't necessary. You simply just need the button wrapped in a default Update Panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Santi but it doesn't work, button not firing the method.

Comment: I removed UseSubmitBehavior and doesn't work, I don't know what is happening to be honest. Is there another way to make the button not refreshing the page without using the UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PostbackTrigger` instead of `AsyncPostbackTrigger` when ChildrenAsTriggers=true.

Comment: Try placing your button outside of the panel and assigning the control attribute only on the trigger.